# Highcharts 3D Scatter Plot: Change Description shown when hovering points

Tags: javascript, highcharts, scatter-plot, scatter3d

I am totally new to Highcharts, and I would like to know, if you can change the content of the "description box" shown for a point, when hovering over it with the mouse.

I tried:
https://jsfiddle.net/by0sxgz1/17/
Using the pointDescriptionFormatter option for a series, but it does not work.

Code Snippet:

```
series: [
{
    name: 'mySeries1',
    accessibility: {
        enabled: true,
        pointDescriptionFormatter: function() {
            return "Hello"
        }
    },
    data: [{x:1, y:1, z:1},{x:2, y:2, z:2}]
}
```

I would like to see "Hello" in the small box over a point (when hovering with the mouse), instead of the normal description, which is Series and the x,y and z values.

What did I get wrong?

I am thankful for any link or tutorial aswell :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your highchart config:

```
tooltip: { 
        useHtml:true,   
        formatter: function() { 
        return "<div style='width:140px;text-align:center;'>Hello!</div>"; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: works perfectly! With the keyword "tooltip" I also found this, which could help others stumbling across the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893035/how-to-customize-tooltip-in-highchart